# Does $\int_0^L \int_0^L \left|\frac{L - x - y}{L} \right| f(x,t) f(y,t) ~ \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$ converge to $f(0,t)^2$ as $L \downarrow 0$?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x,t): \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow [0,M]$ be continuously differentiable in $x$ and where $M < \infty$. I am trying to find the following limit
$$
\underset{L \downarrow 0}{\lim} ~ \int_0^L \int_0^L \left|\frac{L - x - y}{L} \right| f(x,t) f(y,t) ~ \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y.
$$
Heuristically, for $x,y \in (0,L)$, as $L$ gets very small $L$, $x$, and $y$ are all approximately equal so that $\left|\frac{L - x - y}{L} \right| \rightarrow 1$.  When $x=0$ and $y=L$ or when $x=L$ and $y=0$, $\frac{L - x - y}{L} = 0$, so these cases can be ignored as they contribute 0 to the integral.  When $x=y=0$ or $x=y=L$, we always have that $\left|\frac{L - x - y}{L} \right| = 1$.

My hand-wavy reasoning leads me to guess that the limit I am looking for is $f(0,t)^2$.  Is this correct?  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes to 0. At any fixed $t$, you are integrating  continuous uniformly bounded functions on the set $[0,L]\times[0,L]$ whose measure goes to 0.